# I am inserting student data into table through hibernate data inserting but success page not open it shows error

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am inserting `Student` data using **Spring,Hibernate,Oracle** , I am facing issue as addressed below,Please do check and help me  resolve

**Mycontroller.java**

```
      @RequestMapping(value ="/registerSuccess" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)
       public ModelAndView registerSuccess(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") 
         Student student,BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return new ModelAndView("register");
        }

        getStudentService().registerStudent(student);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("welcome");
        modelAndView.addObject("student", student);
        return modelAndView;

      }
```

**Student.java**

```
    package com.infotech.model;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

     import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
     import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "student_table")
    public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id" ,columnDefinition="NUMBER")
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp="[^0-9]+")
    @Size(min=6,max=20)
    @Column(name = "student_name")
    private String studentName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @Size(min=1)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "technology")
    private String technology;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 1000000000)
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private Long phone;
    //getters and setters

    }
```

**StudentService.java**

```
   package com.infotech.service;

   import com.infotech.model.Student;

    public interface StudentService {
    public abstract Student validateStudentCredential(String email, String 
     password);
      public abstract boolean registerStudent(Student student);

     }
```

**StuentDAo.java**

```
package com.infotech.dao;

   import com.infotech.model.Student;

     public interface StudentDAO {
    public abstract boolean saveStudent(Student student);
    public Student getStudentDetailsByEmailAndPassword(String email,String 
  password);
    }
```

**StudentCredential.java**

```
  package com.infotech.model;

  import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
  import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

  public class StudentCredential {

    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    }
```

**StudentServiceImpl.java**

```
    package com.infotech.service.impl;

   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

   import com.infotech.dao.StudentDAO;
    import com.infotech.model.Student;
    import com.infotech.service.StudentService;

    @Service("studentService")
    public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentDAO studentDAO;

    public void setStudentDAO(StudentDAO studentDAO) {
        this.studentDAO = studentDAO;
    }

    public StudentDAO getStudentDAO() {
        return studentDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean registerStudent(Student student) {
        boolean isRegister=false;
        boolean saveStudent = getStudentDAO().saveStudent(student);
        if(saveStudent)
            isRegister=true;
        return isRegister;
    }

    @Override
    public Student validateStudentCredential(String email, String password) 
    {
        Student student = 
      getStudentDAO().getStudentDetailsByEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        return student;
    }
    }
enter code here

  I am using database oracle 11g xe edition in that table 



  CREATE TABLE  "STUDENT_TABLE" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(11,0), 
    "STUDENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(65), 
    "GENDER" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "TECHNOLOGY" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(65), 
    "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(65), 
    "PHONE" NUMBER(20,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "STUDENT_TABLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
   ) ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_STUDENT_TABLE" 
  before insert on "STUDENT_TABLE"               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW."ID" is null then 
    select "STUDENT_TABLE_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."ID" from dual; 
  end if; 
end;
```

> Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [insert into student_table (city, email, gender, password, phone, student_name, technology) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; could not insert: [com.infotech.model.Student]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.infotech.model.Student]

Comment: Please add the screenshot for error and also post your code snippet for the same.

Comment: hi bayya please check it once

Comment: Is data inserted...? have u checked in DB

Comment: yes data successfully inserted but success page shows error

Comment: SQL state [99999]; error code [17004] occurs when there is column mismatch. Have a look at the input and data types specified for the same.

Comment: i confused to find out

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate: insert into student_inforamtion (city, fname, lname, mobile_number) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

this type of error is their do not sue Lombok use manually getter setters

Comment: Please rephrase your explanation. As it is, its meaning is a mystery to me.

Comment: Whoever upvoted this, if you see a useful answer in this, then please [edit] this to make that answer more obvious; ideally according to [answer]. Otherwise ... why did you?